# Python: Using Tkinter radio-buttons to add/remove fields from GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently working on a GUI-based (Tkinter) project used to reduce matrices, just for practice. 
Before I dive into the actual math stuff, I'm working on a basic window to ask the user for information to format their matrix.

In one field, I have radio-buttons - one is "Fraction", the other is "Decimal" - they can choose either for their output format. What I want is, if the user chooses "Decimal", another Entry field will appear below so that they can enter the number of decimals to round to, and if they choose "Fraction", the field won't appear.

I've searched around a bit on Stack Overflow, and saw a bit about using "raise()" and "lower()" methods, but it's not working right now. If you guys can give any input, that would be great. General feedback about the GUI is also appreciated - I learned GUIs in Python in school a while back, so if the format is bad, let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm running Python 3.4.

```
import tkinter

class Reducer:
'''
Takes user input of a matrix and row-reduces it to RREF.

GUI-Based interface that asks the user for the # of rows and columns, as well as output formatting.
The program can output as a fraction or a decimal with a specified number of decimals.
'''


def __init__(self):
    '''
    Initializes the GUI interface that asks the user for input.

    No parameters or returns.
    '''

    self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

    #Initalize frames.
    self.info_frame = tkinter.Frame()
    self.size_frame = tkinter.Frame()
    self.format_frame = tkinter.Frame()
    self.digit_frame = tkinter.Frame()
    self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame()

    #Object for the information frame.
    self.info_label = tkinter.Label(self.info_frame, text="Enter the number of rows and columns, your preferred output format,"
                                           " and the number of trailing decimals if applicable.", justify="left",
                                    wraplength=275).pack()

    #Objects for the size frame - the matrix's rows/columns are set here.
    self.row_label = tkinter.Label(self.size_frame, text="Rows:").pack(side="left")
    self.row = tkinter.Entry(self.size_frame, width=3).pack(side="left")
    self.col_label = tkinter.Label(self.size_frame, text="Columns:").pack(side="left")
    self.col = tkinter.Entry(self.size_frame, width=3).pack(side="left")

    #Objects for the digit frame
    self.digit_label = tkinter.Label(self.digit_frame, text="Digits:")
    self.digit = tkinter.Entry(self.digit_frame, width=3)
    self.digit_label.pack(side="left")
    self.digit.pack(side="left")

    #Objects for the format frame - the output formatting is specified here.
    self.output_var = tkinter.IntVar()
    self.output_var.set(0)

    self.fraction = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.format_frame, text="Fraction", variable=self.output_var, value=0,
                                        command=self.hide_digits()).pack(side="left")

    self.decimal = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.format_frame, text="Decimal", variable=self.output_var, value=1,
                                       command=self.show_digits()).pack(side="left")

    #Object for the bottom frame

    self.button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text="Next", command=self.reduce).pack()

    #Pack frames.
    self.info_frame.pack(anchor="nw")
    self.size_frame.pack(anchor="nw")
    self.format_frame.pack(anchor="nw")
    self.digit_frame.pack(anchor="nw")
    self.button_frame.pack(anchor="nw")

    tkinter.mainloop()

def show_digits(self):
    self.digit_label.lift(self.col)
    self.digit.lift(self.col)

def hide_digits(self):
    self.digit_label.lower(self.col)
    self.digit.lower(self.col)

def reduce(self):
    pass



reducer = Reducer()
```

Comment: You could create a new entry field, rather than using lift/raise etc. this should work.

Comment: @W1ll1amvl, is there a way to remove the entry field once the user clicks "Fraction" again?

Comment: yes there is i think using `nameofvariable.destroy()` will work. I will test it and post an answer if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I mentioned earlier! this makes a new entry field (one at any time).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

global num
num = 0

def create():
    global entry
    global num
    if num == 0:
        num = 1
        entry = tk.Entry()
        entry.pack()

def destroy():
    global entry
    global num
    if num == 1:
        num = 0
        entry.destroy()

button1 = tk.Button(text = 'create entry', command = create)
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(text = 'destroy entry', command = destroy)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

you could also disable and enable the entry field like this, but then the widget is always there so it's up to you:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

global entry
entry = tk.Entry(state = 'disabled')
entry.pack()

def create():
    global entry
    entry.config(state = 'normal')


def destroy():
    global entry
    entry.config(state = 'disabled')

button1 = tk.Button(text = 'create entry', command = create)
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(text = 'destroy entry', command = destroy)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Used the first method and it worked! Thanks a lot. 

I realize that I shouldn't have brackets - like
command=self.hide_digits()

Is there a reason why it should just be self.hide_digits?

Comment: @Spike If you are defining a command, you give the name of the function, but not with parentheses as this 'tries' to call the function. Basically the reason is that this is the way python works i suppose :).